What happens if CRC fails and errors are not detected?
Suppose you want to send a message M and let R be the CRC obtained using a generating polynomial G.
Thus, we send the "redundant" message
M' = [M R].
Now, suppose that during the transmission, the message arrives corrupted by errors to receiver. Let's call it M'', with M'' != M'.
Suppose now that the receiver classifies M'' as "good", i.e. the CRC algorithms gives 0 as remainder when "dividing" M'' by G.
Even thought I know that this is a very rare situation, what would a communication system do in such a situation? Is the received "doomed" to use the collected "trash data"? How can this affect the quality of the communication?

Most communications is done in levels. The lowest levels must be correct before we accept the next level.
You want to send an array of bytes from A to B. A added a CRC which B checked and removed. But B may still receive incorrect data. Often data with a faulty CRC is completely ignored.
Now say A actually sent a Unicode string in UTF-8 encoding. If B received incorrect bytes, then they are likely not a valid Unicode string in UTf-8 format. So the next higher level will be told “there was an error” instead of being told about the string. On the next higher level maybe the string was supposed to contain JSON data. So some code will parse it. Randomly modified bytes are very unlikely to be a valid JSON document.
At some point you reach a level where your application expects data that it can handle. If it received data that it doesn’t understand it’s up to you to handle it.
So typically you have various levels that are supposed to either receive valid data in a certain format and report that it was received, or report that an error happened. The first levels don’t change any state, just report data that was received or that an error happened. For testing purposes, each level can be replaced with code that doesn’t call the previous level but just reports an outcome at some point in time. The application level then either processes the data, or determines that it is incorrect, and decides whether it wants to partially accept correct bits or not

The CRCs used in real systems are very robust. Here is a list of some standard CRC polynomials.
As an example, let us take the CRC-32 used in the Ethernet protocol. For this, the probability of misdetecting an error will be approximately $0.0002328$.
See here and here for the detailed calculations.
Even if we are that unlucky and an erroneous packet is not detected correctly by the CRC, there is still hope. As there will be other protocol-specific checking (possibly in the upper layers), the error can still be detected.

If the CRC is the only means of error correction/detection, there is nothing one can do about this at the coding level. Higher level protocols may have other means of detecting if a message is "off" in some way, maybe once converted into ASCII the decoded message makes no sense and this is determined at higher levels.
No code is able to detect and/or correct all errors anyway, so when we design the code, we would like to determine the probability of such undetected errors, and make it small enough.
Note that the CRC check is a linear operation. So an error pattern is undetected if and only if it is the difference (equivalently XOR sum) of two codewords, i.e., another codeword.
Therefore the probability of undetected error is given by
$$
\sum_{c \in C} Pr[error = c ]=\sum_{d\leq k\leq n} A_k \epsilon^k (1-\epsilon)^{n-k}
$$
where $A_k$ is the number of codewords of weight $k$ and $\epsilon$ is the probability of bit error, which is assumed to be independent and the same for each position in the codeword. $n$ is the length of the code $C$, and $d$ is its minimum distance.
